# Problem of two Facebook Application Collision in my android mobile

Tags: android, facebook

Here is my problem of facebook application i used following example to integrate a post from my application to facebook.
[Here is my reference link for facebook example](https://www.suresome.com/proxy/nph-secure/00A/http/w2davids.wordpress.com/android-facebook-integration/)

1:First thing is that it works perfectly, when no other facebook application is installed in my android mobile. For example application of facebook from android market.

2:So now when I have already installed facebook application from market of android and now when i try to post any message from my facebook application it is divert to in built application of facebook.

Basically when we integrate facebook api to other application it's appear dialog box with login page. As i said before in my application it does not appear.

I don't known why this happens? I also try to maintain my application package name unique as facebook api has .can any body help me?Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I having same problem with my app..!! please help if u found the solution..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all your answers to Facebook SSO issues [here](http://sean.lyn.ch/2011/07/android-the-facebook-sdk-sso-and-you/). You can also avoid sso by adding FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH value into the authorize method’s activityCode parameter. This is not recommended. There is fully explained solution in the link, you can read up and use that.